# Incorrect Calculations in Pivot table when adding a measure

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have made a pivot table of data in which there is a row label and two columns - sum of amount and sum of the actual cost of units, also I have added a measure (profit) which has the formula of subtraction between two sums column.

After adding the profit measure to the pivot table values, the calculated individual profit values are all incorrect and grand total is also incorrect.

How to fix the incorrect values?

screen shot of result from pivot table:
[image]

screen shot of measure for profit column:
[image]

Comment: Do the calculations without pivot tables, if you understand the calcs then you will find the error.

Comment: @SolarMike it is working without pivot table, by just subtracting the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Changing the formula to

```
=SUM([Amount]) - SUM([Actual cost of units])
```

Comment: This is working but what's the difference between the two, isn't the screen shot one the same thing, is it some kind of bug or a standard method in which we have to write the formula ?

Comment: @Vivaan check the detail, what is in the answer has brackets in different positions...